# Rxjava2 with Retrofit get single and all data

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I started to learn some usage with Retrofit and Rxjava2. I am trying to get all countries from https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/ But cant get my head around it. I wish to get all from url above and sigle like so https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/usa. Can you help me achive that.

```
public interface ApiService {

@GET("country/{country_id}")
Single<Country> getCountryData(@Path("name") String name);

@GET("country/{country_id}")
Call<Country> getAllCountries(@Path("array") String name);
}
```

Country:

```
public class Country {

@Expose
@SerializedName("name")
private Integer name;
@Expose
@SerializedName("capital")

private String capital;
@Expose
@SerializedName("population")
private int population;

}
```

MainClass:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Get all
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
            apiService.getAllCountries("array").subscribe(new SingleObserver<Country>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                // we'll come back to this in a moment
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Country country) {
                // data is ready and we can update the UI
                Log.d("DTAG",country.getName());
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // oops, we best show some error message
            }
        });;

        //Gat Single
        Retrofit retrofitSingle = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all/USA")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiService apiServiceSingle = retrofitSingle.create(ApiService.class);
        apiServiceSingle.getAllCountries("array").subscribe(new SingleObserver<Country>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                // we'll come back to this in a moment
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Country country) {
                // data is ready and we can update the UI
                Log.d("DTAG","");
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // oops, we best show some error message
            }
        });;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. baseUrl should be `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/`
2. The key you pass to the `@Path` annotation has to be the same that you have in your relative url. Eg

   ```
   @GET("name/{country_id}")
   Single<List<Country>> getCountry(@Path("country_id}") String name)
   ```

in this case, if you call `service.getCountry("usa")`, the yielded url will be

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/usa

The endpoint returns a json array, so you will have to change `Single<Country>` in `Single<List<Country>>`